# Which is the conjugated form for "müssen" in the present tense? Is it "ich muss" or "ich muß"?

Tags: modal-verb, umlaut

I learned it from my German teacher as *muß*. But I'm reading a lot of notes on the Internet that say it's *muss* and others that it's *muß*. Has there been an official change in the German language recently or something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There has been a spelling reform some 15 years ago. Since then it's supposed to be

> "muss"

because the "u" is short and closed. Today, "ß" only follows long vowels (for example Straße or Maß) so "muß" would technically sound like English "moose".

However, a lot of people are still used to the old way plus the reform wasn't exactly whole heartedly received which lead to a good deal of confusion. So some youngster in a forum might actually write "muss" and then correct himself to "muß" simply because a vague awareness that there has been a confusing reform so the first impulse was probably wrong.

Comment: Actually, the puree is spelled "Mus". And about the teacher: he is unfit to work as such. To use old spelling privately is ok, but not as a teacher.

Comment: @Veredomon... ops, thanks :). I have my issues with the rules, too, it appears.

Comment: @Veredomon: Well, we don’t know, *when* this was taught. It might have been twenty years ago.

Comment: @Verodom: Good point.

Comment: @Veredomon... did you just ping yourself? :)

Comment: @Emanuel: Yes, we do that from time to time.